# How can I click button on popup? (pupeteer-sharp)

Tags: c#, puppeteer-sharp

When I click to button, page of pop-up is opening. I have to click button on it. How can I do it?

````
await page.GoToAsync("https://.....");```
await page.WaitForTimeoutAsync(7000 * 2);```
await page.WaitForSelectorAsync("a[class='visit_button']");```
await page.ClickAsync("a[class='visit_button']"); //open popup``` 
await page.WaitForTimeoutAsync(3000);``` 
// I click to button on pop-up```
````

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
var alertMessage = "";
//attach to page during entire page life-cycle (until closed).
//handles the case where an javscript alert comes up during login.
page.Dialog += new EventHandler<DialogEventArgs>(async (sender, args) =>
{
    alertMessage = args.Dialog.Message;
    await args.Dialog.Accept(); //this closes it..
    Log.Information("Popup squashed in Login(): {0}", alertMessage);
    Thread.Sleep(500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [PageEventsPopupTests](https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp/blob/master/lib/PuppeteerSharp.Tests/PageTests/PageEventsPopupTests.cs) :

```
await page.GoToAsync("https://.....");

await page.ClickAsync("a[class='visit_button']"); //Open Popup

var popupTaskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<Page>();
page.Popup += (_, e) => popupTaskSource.TrySetResult(e.PopupPage);
await popupTaskSource.Task;

var popupPage = popupTaskSource.Task.Result; // Popup Page

await popupPage.ClickAsync("a[class='btn']"); //Click on button in popup page
```